# Django: how to install tinymce?

Tags: python, django

1- I want to install [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com). not [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/) (**for some reason**)

2-I don't want to do it using the **admin.py** method (**for some reason**)

---

I want to do it my way:

in **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     (url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      (r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                               { 'document_root': 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/django-projects/cms/javascript/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce' },

    )))
```

in  **admin/flatpages/flatpage/change_form.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ jsi18nurl|default:"../../../jsi18n/" }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode: "textareas",
theme: "simple"
});
```

2 days ago i didn't get any errors but tinymce won't show, now, I tried to do it again and i get this error

```
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 22)
```

**UPDATE**

`invalid syntax (urls.py, line 22)` is gone

now i see `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 23; 2 is required`

**@Denis Kabalkin**

**IF** i do it like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                               { 'document_root': 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/django-projects/cms/javascript/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce' }),
)
```

I get `invalid syntax (urls.py, line 12)`

**IF** I do it like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{ 'document_root': 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/django-projects/cms/javascript/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce'}),
    )
```

I'll see no error but TinyMce will not be displayed[image]

Comment: What version of tinymce are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes the errors in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                               { 'document_root': 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/django-projects/cms/javascript/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce' }),
)
```

Here is [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url).

Comment: Now look at page source code in browser, look for tinymce path and try to open it.

Comment: hey i got it to work by copying change_form.html from 'admin/flatpages/flatpage/change_form.html' to 'admin/change_form.html'

Comment: thanks for helping solving the other error brother and helping me with this one

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect; there ought to be 2 times `url`; and the `23` is the `len('^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$')`. Don't know why this answer was upvoted so much and accepted.

Comment: It seems that the **correct answer is in pastebin**, yay.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis on line 22

Comment: i was missing 2 parenthesis :) now the error disappears but i have this error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 23; 2 is required